# Pressing Spacebar on Logitech K350 moves page to the bottom

Tags: keyboard

Out of the blue I am having trouble with my Logitech K350 keyboard. When I press the spacebar whatever page I am on starts scrolling down with each press. While I'm typing something like this it seems to work ok, but on other webpages it scrolls down and will even cause text on page to be highlighed. Any ideas how I can stop this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is the normal behavior of space bar in a webpage on modern browsers - scroll one page at a time.

If your cursor focus is in a text box or somewhere to type it should not scroll but if you are outside of any text boxes, that is normal.